# What is the purpose of DIFS (Distributed Inter-Frame Space) in 802.11?

Tags: networking

If a station senses that the channel is idle, it transmits its frame after a short period of time, called DIFS (Distributed Inter-Frame Space). Why can't it transmit its data immediately?

Answer (score 3):

SIFS, DIFS, and EIFS are just standard pauses used to coordinate contention:

http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr01/wrlslans/80211_page2.htm

Answer (score 3):

Your phrasing is a bit confusing. It's not that the station senses the channel idle, then waits. It *waits* in order to *sense* if the channel is idle.

Also, an idle station doesn't usually spend all its time listening out. It shuts down to save power, turning on the receiver only for the beacons, which tell it that a frame is waiting for this. So, if a station in power save wants to transmit, it would need to wake up, then listen out for a while (DIFS), and then transmit.